# SQL Merge returning all the rows from target on match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL Merge statement.

```
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (BusinessBaseID int, BatchID uniqueidentifier, SupplierID int, SupplierVenueID varchar(200), AddressID int,[Action] varchar(50))

DECLARE @noop int;  -- needed for the NO-OP below
Declare @TestOp Varchar(max)
Set @TestOp = 't'

-- Insert into BusinessBase retrieving all inserted BusinessBaseIDs mappings via tmptable
-- Another SQL blck goes here to insert records into TEMP table

MERGE Business.Address AS t 
USING (SELECT tmp.BusinessBaseID, tmp.BatchID, tmp.SupplierID, tmp.SupplierVenueID,
v.Name, v.AddressLine1, v.AddressLine2, v.City, v.County, v.PostalCode,
v.Latitude, 
v.Longitude, 
dbo.GetVenueId(v.AddressLine1, v.AddressLine2, v.City, v.County, v.PostalCode, 'GB', v.Latitude, v.Longitude) as VenueId
FROM @TmpTable as tmp INNER JOIN Supplier.VenueImport as v
ON tmp.BatchID = v.BatchID AND tmp.SupplierID = v.SupplierID AND tmp.SupplierVenueID = v.SupplierVenueID
WHERE (tmp.BatchID = 'D7F369F1-A66A-4440-8D4B-2F521F672916') AND (tmp.SupplierID = 17)
) AS s
ON S.VenueId >0
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET @TestOp = @TestOp + ':' +convert(varchar, S.VenueId)+'|'+Convert(varchar,t.AddressId)  -- the NO-OP instead of update
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, StateProvince,PostalCode,CountryCode,Lat,Long)
  VALUES (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, County, PostalCode, 'GB', Latitude, Longitude)
OUTPUT s.BusinessBaseID, s.BatchID, s.SupplierID, s.SupplierVenueID,ISNULL(INSERTED.AddressID,deleted.addressId),$action INTO @TmpTable;

Select @TestOp;
Select @Temp where [Action] = 'Update'
```

Above query returning all the rows (except newly inserted records). Where as it suppose to return only 1 record as S.VenueId is greater than 0 for only one record.

```
dbo.GetVenueId is a function which returns an integer. It will be > 0 for existing records and -1 for not existing records.
```

Could somebody point me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: Your business.address has only one record? Otherwise, `ON S.VenueId > 0 AND ... ` where the ... is an aditional condition that, for instance, equals an id of `S` with an id of `T`

Comment: No Business.Address has more than 20k records. But there is only such record which returns S.VenueId > 0 all other records will be returning -1.

Comment: Do notice that `ON S.VenueId >0` only applies to the table you are using. If you want that condition also on Business.Address you must write `AND t.VenueId > 0`, otherwise your merge will apply to all rows of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the call dbo.GetVenueId to the following

CASE dbo.GetVenueId(v.AddressLine1, v.AddressLine2, v.City, v.County, v.PostalCode, 'GB', v.Latitude, v.Longitude) WHEN -1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END as VenueId

So It will act well